# kendo ui maps mvc is not showing bing maps tile

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, sitefinity, kendo-map

I have a Kendo UI Html helper for creating a Kendo Map. I am able to bind remote data and display the markers. However the map tiles do not show up on the page. I am not sure what to do. Here is my markup. The mvc site is created as a Widget to use within sitefinity.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Map()
            .Name("trailerLocationMap")
            .Center(33.066826, -96.804286)
            .Zoom(4)
            .Layers(layers =>
            {
                    layers.Add()
                .Type(MapLayerType.Bing)
                .ImagerySet(MapLayersImagerySet.Road)
                 .Key("myKey");

            })
```

)

Comment: The problem was due to Sitefinity web app blocking the bing content. I ended up scrapping this an going with google instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using sitefinity 11 or above you need to add the Bing URLs to the web security configs. https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/web-security-module